# 2 iPhone apps messed up when deploy to iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have 2 iPhone apps and want to deploy to iphone and somehow the second app rewrote the first app on my iPhone.

The second app project was copied from the first app and I made some changes including renaming the app name etc.

I believe there might be some files messed up due to the shared path. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the two application's bundle identifiers are different, otherwise they will be treated as different versions of the same app.

Look for the *CFBundleIdentifier* (Bundle Identifier) key in your application's Info plist.  Make sure this is different for each application.